# Datatables pagination hide 1 2 3 page button and have Next - Previoud Button ony

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, datatables

I have used datadables.net pagination for my html table. And i want to hide/remove the 1 2 3 ... buttons in pagination and have only Next and Previous Buttons on it.

Is it Possible like doing pagingnumbers: false,(something like this simple change in code) ?

My Function:-

```
$('#pagination').DataTable( {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 2,
            "bFilter": false
        } );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 options:

```
simple - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons only
simple_numbers - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons, plus page numbers
full - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons
full_numbers - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers
So in your case :

 $('#pagination').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "simple",
        "iDisplayLength": 2,
        "bFilter": false
    } );
```

Comment: Thanks Man. It was Helpfull :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set...

```
"pagingType": "full",
```

Here you can find all posible combinations...

https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you too Man. :)   Helpful :)